# Passing a param from cmd line to package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    ...
  },
```

I'm using a package that runs via npm start. I want to pass params to the start command.

How can I pass the param in the command line?

```
npm start --myparam = hello
```

Alos, how can I access this in my package.jspn file to pass through to gulp:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "gulp --myparam",
    ...
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to run `gulp --myparam=hello` with the `npm start` command.

The correct way to do this is `npm start -- --myparam=hello`.

Notice the `--` in the command. Anything after the `--` will be passed directly to the start command (`gulp`).

The reason for requiring the `--` is that `npm start` (and `npm run`) can take parameters as well; like `-s` to silence the default output from `npm`.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. Thanks. WIll accept asap.

Comment: Glad I could help!